# How to ignore nested of nested objects with ProjectTo in Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to ignore nested nested objects when loading lazily?

```cs
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children;
}

public class Child
{
    public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects;
}
```

When defining Parent, you need to ignore the Someobject field inside Children, **but when defining only Child, you don't need to ignore it**.

Is this possible without adding a copy of Child class without a field?
It is necessary not just to delete the object, but to ignore it during the SQL query.

```cs
//SomeObjects inside Child must be empty
var parent = _mapper.ProjectTo<ParentDTO>(_dbContext.Parent.Where(c => c.Id == id)).FirstOrDefault();

//not ignored SomeObjects inside Child
var child = _mapper.ProjectTo<ChildDTO>(_dbContext.Children.Where(c => c.Id == id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you tried using [ExplicitExpansion](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion) in your mapping configuration for your `Parent` type?

Comment: @WBuck i tried, but i dont know how to use ExplicitExpansion() for nested field to Child from CreateMap<Parent, ParentDTO> so that it does not concern CreateMap<Child, ChildDTO>

Comment: @WBuck Solved the problem, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the following way

```cs
CreateMap<Child, ChildDTO>
  .ForMember(_ => _.SomeObjects, opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion())
  .ForAllMembers(_ => _.UseDestinationValue());

//calls
var parent = _mapper.ProjectTo<ParentDTO>(_dbContext.Parents.Where(c => c.Id == id)).FirstOrDefault();

var client = _mapper.ProjectTo<ChildDTO>(
                    _dbContext.Children.Where(c => c.Id == id),
                    null,                    
                    c => c.SomeObjects  //include SomeObjects
                ).FirstOrDefault();
```